# Swift: Result of call to function within viewWillTransition is unused

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a calendar cocoapod (CVCalendar: https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar) which has two view types; weekView and monthView. The following function is required in the pod and I have it within a class extension:

```
 func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {

    let isPhone: Bool = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    let isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape

    if isPhone == true && isLandscape == true {
        return.weekView
    } else {
            return .monthView
    }
}
```

I am trying to present the weekView if the calendar is showing on an IPhone in landscape, or the monthView if it is showing on anything else. I am then calling the function in viewWillTransition:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

       self.presentationMode()

    }
```

However when use the code above I get the warning 'Result of call to 'presentationMode' is unused and the view does not change to weekView in IPhone Lanscape.

Comment: First in `presentationMode()` everything after the first line `return.weekView` will not execute because you are returning from the function. The warning is because the return value from `presentationMode()` is not assigned to anything, it should be setting the `CVCalendar`'s `CalendarMode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the functions

```
func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
    let isPhone: Bool = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    let isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape

    if isPhone == true && isLandscape == true {
        return.weekView
    } else {
        return .monthView
    }
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    self.calendarView.calendarMode = self.presentationMode()
    self.calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is updating the calendar to weekView when tested so thanks! However, the calendars day buttons/icons within the view are staying in the same place. I have tried adding view.layoutIfNeeded within the viewWillTransition function but this also doesnt affect it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah no problem. You solved my initial problem anyways so thanks!